# Ubuntu 19.04 show applications box

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image]I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 19.04 on my Dell XPS-15.

The Dock seems to be minimized to a small box, when you hoover over it come up with "Show Applications". I have clicked on this box and nothing happens.

How does one view the Dock?

Comment: I've added an image, can't take a screenshot given I can't open applications

Comment: I don't recognize this desktop as 19.04. you've seen screenshots right? your upgrade must have failed. try installing 19.04 from a Live USB

Comment: I didn't see any failure in the upgrade. All the Gnome Shell extensions are missing. I managed to xfer a file via KDE but the icons are missing from that application. I would appreciate a suggestion how to create a Live USB, ie) software to use.

Comment: you do not need anything ubuntu comes with usb Live cd creator preinstalled. it is the best software for this. you download the iso here : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=FR&version=19.04&architecture=amd64 and then you plug a usb of minimum 4GB, then hit start and type "usb" or Ctl+Alt+T, to open a terminal window and inside it type `usb-creator-gtk` and then just click create

Comment: That worked, although have to reinstall some software, thanks. I note that the NVIDIA driver has changed (tested) from 18.10 to 19.04. Was using NVIDIA 390 on 18.10 now, NVIDIA 419. I wonder if that was the issue.

Comment: no everyone except you was already using 418. it's just you had to know that you could and install a PPA. now ubuntu installs this PPA itself and pre-installs 418. drivers cannot alter Desktop Environement behavior. just frames per second.

Comment: Ok, do I mark it or do u? If so, how. Again, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend upgrading ubuntu version to new users, nor to anyone else.

perhaps one day that feature will work the way windows 7/8 upgrade to windows 10 does.

today is not that day.

I strongly recomend you backup your data to a usb or external hard drive and make a fresh install of ubuntu 19.04.

ubuntu 19.04 works fine it's my daily driver.

to make an install live USB of ubuntu 19.04 click this link : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=FR&version=19.04&architecture=amd64

select "keep" when it finishes downloading, then open up the USB disk creator by typing <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, to open a terminal window and inside it type `usb-creator-gtk` and then just click create.

you can then reboot and choose this USB key to boot to (choose UEFI if it shows up twice)